# Retrieve z from a constrained delaunay triangulation of Projection_traits_xy_3

Tags: cgal

Given `x,y`, how can I retrieve the `z` coordinate of a 2D constrained delaunay triangulation built from 2.5D with `projection_traits_xy_3`?

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<Gt> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> CDT;
```

My guess is that I have to retrieve the face, but what would be the next step?

```
CDT::Point query(10,10,?);   
CDT::Face_handle face_handle = cdt.locate(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andreas pointed out, the triangulation stores 3d points even if it uses its 2d projection. Therefore, we can retrieve the `Point_3`.

Given the query point `(x,y) = (100,100)`:

```
//z unknown
Point query1(100, 100, 0);

CDT::Face_handle face_handle = cdt.locate(query1);

K::Point_3 p = face_handle->vertex(0)->point();
K::Point_3 q = face_handle->vertex(1)->point();
K::Point_3 r = face_handle->vertex(2)->point();
```

Answer (score 1):

Triangulation::Point will be a 3D  point, so `face_handle->vertex(0)->point()` will be a 3D point with a z-coordinate.

Comment: Correct. I had figure it out. I've posted the complete answer.